# Python SequenceMatcher (difflib) not providing correct results for delete tag

Tags: python, list, compare, difflib, sequencematcher

I'm using SequenceMatcher to compare the output of usernames from an API list and an LDAP group. The intent is to add, and separately, remove users.

I've got the 'add' part working. I can't get the 'remove' part to give me the correct list of usernames.

All I'm doing is swapping around 'a' and 'b'. So if it works when computing 'how to I get from a to b', surely the same should apply if asking 'how do I get from b to a'?

Here's the content of my lists, with the username that exists in both highlighted.

a:
['**user1**', 'user2']

b:
['usera', 'userb', 'userc', 'userd', '**user1**', 'userx', 'usery']

```
def compare_two_lists(a, b, action):
    users_to_add = []
    users_to_delete = []
    if action == 'add':
        s = SequenceMatcher(None, a, b)
        for tag, i1, i2, j1, j2 in s.get_opcodes():
            if tag in ('insert', 'replace'):
                users_to_add.append(b[j1:j2])
        print('Add:')
        print(users_to_add)
    if action == 'delete':
        s = SequenceMatcher(None, b, a)
        print('a:')
        print(a)
        print('b:')
        print(b)
        for tag, i1, i2, j1, j2 in s.get_opcodes():
            if tag == 'delete':
                users_to_delete.append(a[i1:i2])
        print('Delete: ')
        print(users_to_delete)
```

The output I get:

> Delete:  [['**user1**', 'user2']]

user1 absolutely should not be in this list, so why is it? user2 should be in this list but as far as I'm concerned it's only there as coincidence and not because SequenceMatcher is actually reporting it properly.

I've messed around with swapping i1:i2, j1:j2, a, b, about as many different variants as I can think of.

Comment: If the order in the lists doesn't actually matter, better use `set` and set operations like `difference` instead of `difflib`.

Comment: @MichaelButscher The order doesn't matter to me, but do you mean to me or to Python? I'm not going to sort or order the lists and I thought this was one way to compare unordered/unsorted lists. It's a bit weird that it works with a to b and not b to a.

Comment: @MichaelButscher I've taken this advice and quickly created a set/compare function which seems to be working, so thanks for the tip.

Comment: I meant if the order matters to you. Set operations are much more suitable here. I don't know the exact algorithm of `difflib` but it was meant to compare things like e. g. source code but not for lists, especially not for unordered ones.